# Couldn't Install (-113) - Android (Xiaomi) Phone

Tags: android-studio

I recently upgrade my Andriod Stuido to the latest version.

I am not able to install any apk built from Android Studio to my Mi 11 Phone.

The following error message is shown:

`Couldn't Install ()-113`

Any hints on why the problems occurs and how it can be solved?

P.S.  My own app built using pervious Android Studio version can still be installed again into my phone now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer myself.

The USB Debugt was turned on in the past but somehow it become off.....